# ¿Como puedo extraer los datos en este JSON mediante javascript y html?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero extraer los datos de este `json` mediante `Javascript` y `HTML`
lo que necesito es mostrar los datos `"ID" y "NAME"`
https://pastebin.com/raw/45M08KT7

```
    {
      "mohademago": {
        "id": 4294825,
        "name": "mohademago",
        "profileIconId": 1594,
        "revisionDate": 1491930966000,
        "summonerLevel": 30
      }
    }
```

Comment: Bastara solo en el javascript en la variables que tengas el JSON : miVariable.mohademago.id y miVariable.mohademago.name; cuida mayúsculas y minúsculas. Como no estas colocando nada de código que ya probaste no puedo sugerirte donde y que modificar.

Answer (score 3):

El siguiente ejemplo te muestra como hacer para:

1.- Acceder a los valores de un Objeto JSON si conoces su estructura.
2.- Acceder a los valores de un Objeto JSON si **NO** se conoce su estructura.
3.- Obtener los datos desde una petición GET (via XMLHttpRequest)
(Esto solo funciona si la solicitud se hace al mismo servidor)

```js
obj = {
      "mohademago": {
        "id": 4294825,
        "name": "mohademago",
        "profileIconId": 1594,
        "revisionDate": 1491930966000,
        "summonerLevel": 30
      }
    };

html.innerHTML+="\
1.- Acceder a los valores de un objeto JSON si conoces su estructura"
html.innerHTML+="<p>id="+obj.mohademago.id;
html.innerHTML+="<p>name="+obj.mohademago.name;

html.innerHTML+="\
2.- Acceder a los valores de un objeto JSON si NO conoces su estructura"
display(obj,"");

function display(obj,sp) {
 for (n in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[n] == 'object') {
   display(obj[n],n+".");
  }else{
   html.innerHTML+="<p>"+sp+n+"="+obj[n];
  }
 }
}

html.innerHTML+="\
3.- Obtener los datos desde una petición GET (via XMLHttpRequest)\
(Esto solo funciona si la solicitud se hace al mismo servidor)"
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://pastebin.com/raw/45M08KT7', true); 
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (req.readyState == 4)
  if  (req.status == 200) {
   obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   display(obj,"");
  } else {
   html.innerHTML+="<p>error "+req.status;
 }
};
req.send(null);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Datos={
      "DatosPersonales": {
        "dni": 70798811,
        "nombre": "Pajaroman",
        "edad": 20,
      }
    };


 $("#dni").html(Datos.DatosPersonales.dni);
 $("#nombre").html(Datos.DatosPersonales.nombre);       $("#edad").html(Datos.DatosPersonales.edad);
 //O de esta foma tambien
 console.log(Datos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dni"></div>
<div id="nombre"></div>
<div id="edad"></div>
```

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] debes colocar una explicación del código; pues le debe ser comprensible no solo a quien preguntó sino al resto de comunidad que consulte

Answer (score 0):

para acceder a los atributos de json, se usa el punto`.` seguido del atributo, ejemplo: `datos.mahademago` y te devuelve una lista

```js
var datos={
      "mohademago": {
        "id": 4294825,
        "name": "mohademago",
        "profileIconId": 1594,
        "revisionDate": 1491930966000,
        "summonerLevel": 30
      }
    };
    
var div=document.getElementById("show");
div.innerHTML=datos.mohademago.id+" "+datos.mohademago.name;
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```